# Subsonic dynamic query expression

Tags: dynamic, subsonic, expression

I am having a few issues with trying to live in a subsonic world and being a subsonic girl when it comes to subsonic expressions....

after reading [Subsonic Query (ConditionA OR ConditionB) AND ConditionC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765896/subsonic-query-conditiona-or-conditionb-and-conditionc) it would appear i am not the only one with this sort of issue but hopefully someone (the almighty rob??) can answer this.

i am attempting to create an expression in my query based on a looping condition. what i want to achieve (in pseudo code) is something like this:

```
objQuery.andexpressionstart();

foreach (condition in conditions){

   if (condition){
      objQuery.and(conditionColumn).isequalto(X);
   }

}
objQuery.expressionstop();
```

my main issue is that each condition that is inside the expression is a different column - otherwise i could just use .In() . i also have extra search criteria (read a fair bit) outside so it can't be outside an expression.

i REALLY don't want to leave the warm coseyness of the strongly-typed-subsonic womb however i think in this instance i might have too... if i DO have to is there a way to add to a subsonic query with a hand typed condition so i don't have to change all the other code in the query (alot of business logic living in subsonic land right now)

As always, thanks for any help
cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't the time to test this right now, but I think if you do something like the following should work:

```
bool isFirstCondition = true;

foreach (condition in conditions){

   if (condition)    
   {
        if(isFirstCondition)
        {
           objQuery.AndExpression(conditionColumn).isequalto(X);
           isFirstCondition = false;
        }
        else
        {  
           objQuery.and(conditionColumn).isequalto(X);

        }
   }

}
```

Make sure all your other conditions have been added prior to the loop.

Comment: i have a problem in the fact that i have more than one "expression"

Comment: my understanding is that when you use "AndExpression" it will group everything until the next "AndExpression" is called.

(first expression and (second expression and ( third expression )))

where each expression can contain any number of criteria.

Try it out and check what SQL is being generated.