# Nested and/or expression in subsonic 2.2

Tags: subsonic

I need to make a query like :

```
SELECT * from TABLE
    WHERE cola= "aaa"
        and
        (
            (colb = "bbb" and (colc="ccc" or colc = "ddd"))
            or
            (colb="eee" and colc = "fff")
        )
```

I tried with `Andexpression()`, `orexpression()`, `openexpression()` or `closeexpression()`, but i can't figure it out !
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

`WhereExpression`, `AndExpression` etc. should work (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765896/subsonic-query-conditiona-or-conditionb-and-conditionc)), but it doesn't work for me all the time, neither.

As long as your `Where` clauses are relatively simple, you could add some repetition and use *logical operator precedence*:

```
SELECT * from TABLE
    WHERE cola="aaa" AND colb="bbb" AND colc="ccc"
          OR
          cola="aaa" AND colb="bbb" AND colc="ddd"
          OR
          cola="aaa" AND colb="eee" AND colc="fff"
```

This would result in something like this:

```
DB.Select().From<TABLE>()
    .Where(TABLE.colaColumn).isEqualTo("aaa")
        .And(TABLE.colbColumn).isEqualTo("bbb")
        .And(TABLE.colcColumn).isEqualTo("ccc")
    .Or(TABLE.colaColumn).isEqualTo("aaa")
        .And(TABLE.colbColumn).isEqualTo("bbb")
        .And(TABLE.colcColumn).isEqualTo("ddd")
    .Or(TABLE.colaColumn).isEqualTo("aaa")
        .And(TABLE.colbColumn).isEqualTo("eee")
        .And(TABLE.colcColumn).isEqualTo("fff")
```